# How to make "outline" frame in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

In a presentation, people show regularly a "outline" frame containing the table of contents where some sections are grey (have been presented) and others are highlighted (will be presented right now).

Could anyone tell me how to realize it? Do we have to copy the same frame (table of contents) every time and change the color of some titles?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do this using `\AtBeginSection`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline for section \thesection}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the frame obtained just before the frames for section two:

[image]

Comment: That highlights the section, but if it has subsections, they are not highlighted. Do you know if there is a way to do that?

Comment: here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193975/highlight-only-current-subsection-hide-subsections-of-other-sections

Answer (score 2):

To get a slide with your table of contents, use

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

or on more recent beamer versions

```
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

While this does not answer exactly the original question, it ends up being useful, as lot of people might visit this thread with this specific goal.

Comment: Have you tested this answer? It does not show the table of contents with highlight for the current section. And even if it would: It is not simpler to copy the frame every time you start a new section than to generate such a frame automatically.

Comment: This is what to do if you want an outline one time at the start of the presentation, but it's not a clean way to have a repeating outline at the start of each section.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer to the wrong question, but it happens to be the answer to the question that I wanted the answer to, so it fits the definition “This answer is useful”, at least to this user at this time.