# Highlight only current subsection, hide subsections of other sections

Tags: beamer, pdftex

The *table of contents* command in my beamer .sty looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\MyToc}[1]
{
    \AtBeginSubsection[]
    {
        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{#1}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections,currentsubsection]
        \end{frame}
    }
}
```

It shows all sections and subsections with emphasis on the current section and subsection, but I want only the subsections of the current section to be shown, the current subsection be emphasized AND subsections of other sections not to be shown at all:

- section 1
- section 2

  - subsection 1 <= inactive, shaded
  - subsection 2 <= active subsection, strong colour
  - subsection 3 <= inactive, shaded
- section 3

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Once again I found the solution in the [docs](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (page 100):

```
    ...
    \tableofcontents
    [
        currentsection,
        currentsubsection,
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
    ]
    ...
```

show   = current subsection is shown regularly

shaded = the section's other subsections are shown, but shaded

hide   = other sections' subsection entries are not shown in the table of contents